# Why was Tony Stark using such a primitive phone in Avengers: Infinity War?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, avengers-infinity-war

After deciding that the only way to defeat Thanos was to reunite the Avengers, Tony Stark takes out his phone to call Captain America. The only problem is, why is Tony - one of the most technological advanced people on Earth - using an old flip phone, you would think he would just use J.A.R.V.I.S. or some other super-cool techie thing?

Comment: It wasn't his phone - it's Tony Stank's.

Comment: FYI - JARVIS no longer exists... "he" "is" Vision now...

Comment: Similar question from sister site - [**Why did Tony Stark use a normal flip phone?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88559/why-did-tony-stark-use-a-normal-flip-phone)

Comment: @Odin1806:   That depends on what the meaning of the word *is* is.

Comment: Just flip that phone few more times and it'd morph into a smartphone (nanotech). If government asks to show his contacts, he can show his smartphone contacts which doesn't have phone number of a terrorist (Captain America).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Tony Stark uses the flip-phone he received from Captain America at the end of *Captain America: Civil War*. As the oft-reliable Marvel Cinematic Universe wiki states:

> Stark found a phone and letter from Steve Rogers, apologizing for keeping the truth about Stark's parents from him, telling Stark if he would need Rogers' help, he and the rest of his team were just a phone call away.

The scene in *Infinity War* in which Stark uses the phone is when he is prompted by Bruce Banner to call Steve Rogers to assist them in the fight against Thanos (although he never does end up using it).

Comment: I could be mis-remembering, but I believe that Bruce still used it.

Comment: @Odin1806 I remember the same. That's why Banner was with Cap's group when they met up with Rhodey.

Comment: So essentially Tony Stark doesn't know how to transfer contacts from one phone to another. Sound's like he's using my wife's old Ericsson.

Comment: @Doomfrost:   No, he just didn't bother.   But why the phone is still charged is another question.

Comment: Maybe it's a 2 way phone and the number on the screen is for show.